# Is there a consensus on the definition of wavelength for a solitary wave?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, solitons

Solitary waves are by definition a wave of single nature so the usual definition for periodic waves does not apply. [R. Dalrymple](http://www.coastal.udel.edu/faculty/rad/solcalc.html) provides  a definition but I saw a lot of other websites and papers which seem to use a wide range of definitions. Is there a
 consensus on the definition of wavelength for a solitary wave?

Comment: The only rigorous sense (that I can think of) in which a non-periodic function can have a wavelength is to take its Fourier Transform and analyze its frequency spectrum. If you know the wave's speed, then by assigning it a frequency width which quantifies its localization in frequency space you can determine an estimate/range for its wavelength. But the more localized the wave is the less local it will be in frequency space, so there is a significant limit to this sort of analysis.